# ICEFaces: values for the "icon" attribute

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-3

I'm writing a menu bar made up of icons.
The easiest way, in my opinion, is relying on the *icon* attribute of the *ace:menuItem* component.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find, neither in the [showcase](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf) nor in the [documentation](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/documentation.jsf), a complete list of the built-in values allowed for that attribute (i.e. *ui-icon*, *ui-icon-contact* etc.).
Where could I find it? In case there isn't such a list, how could I work it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the source of the page, then open theme.css
Have a look at: 
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html

Comment: Thanks! :-) Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote :-(